# html agility pack url scraping href

Tags: html-agility-pack

Hi I am using html agility pack from the nuget packages in order to scrape a web page to get all of the urls on the page. I use this code for get all links in a body site:

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
```

in a one site i have a problem, a href is in this mode:

```
<a data-v-b2e8c352="" href="#/">Home</a>

<a data-v-b2e8c352="" href="#/subscribe" class="">My subscription</a>
```

Comment: whats the error you getting when you use that `SelectNodes` statement?

Comment: return nothing, no record

Comment: Do you check the source of web page? Are these elements in fact in a <iframe> (which will include an embedded page) element?